# Animate like Stack exchange frequently asked questions

Tags: plugins, jquery

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/about

As you scroll down the page, images and text slowly fading. Is there a plug-in origin jquery like string that I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common method is based on scroll position and if the item is visible. When it becomes visible they fire an event.

Here's an answer with a bit of code I'd check out.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/1251604